# disable dates in jquery calendar between today's date and set date and also weekends if it comes

Tags: php, jquery, calendar

Suppose today date is 11-6-2013

```
$("#departure").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: "+1y",
             minDate: +4,
        });
$("#departure").datepicker("setDate", "5");
<input id="departure" />
```

here 15 and 16 are weekends so it should not come and it should be skip and comes 18-3-2013.
Please help me.
See Here:-
here this one is working perfect:-
[image]

but in screenshot 15 and 16 falls on sat and sun so it should be skip and 17 and 18 should come.

Comment: So you want to select the next workday on datepicker init ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable weekends, jquery ui has a built in function for it. Add `beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends` on datepicker init. ref: api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
$("#departure").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: "+1y",
    minDate: +4
});
```

Comment: Hello @soderslatt, if i am writing beforeshowDay then my 5 days are not disabled,only weekends are disabling.i want my 5 days disable + if any weekends comes in betwen 5 days then it should be skip.and next days should consider.

Comment: please specify your problem more in your question. Do you want to disable 5 days, do you want to disable 5 working-days or something else?

Answer (score 0):

To disable specific date you can handle using `beforeShowDay` and custom function.

```
var unavailableDates = ["9-5-2011","14-5-2011","15-5-2011"];

function unavailable(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
    return [true,"","Custom message here"];
  } else {
    return [false,"","Custom message here"];
  }
}

$('#departure').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: unavailable });
```

To disable weekends you can use `beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends` as 
@soderslatt mention in answer.

Live demo [here](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/07/disable-weekends-in-jquery-ui.html)

Comment: Hello @roopendra, i wnat to disable 5 days from current dates.but in this 5 days if there is sun or sat comes it should be skip this 2 days and next 2 days should come.In unavailableDates what i should write?

Comment: @User25, in unavailableDates variable we will take 5days,  we need to find way so that it can't take weekends. and `beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,` we are already disable weekends.

Comment: you know this 5 days is dynamic means from current date it should take 5 days, means every day it will change.@roopendra

Comment: yes i understand. But I am finding a way how it will skip weekends and count 5 days. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Collection Date</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" /> 

    </head>
<body>
<form name="Form1" method="post" action="TestDatePicker.asp" id="Form1">

<h2>Collection Form</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Choose the collection date</legend>

    <div id="datepicker"></div>
    <input type="text" id="txtCollectionDate" name="txtCollectionDate" class="requiredField" style="display: none;" />

</fieldset>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var dateMin = new Date();
        //alert(dateMin);
        var weekDays = AddWeekDays(5);
        alert(weekDays);
        alert(weekDays);

        dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate() + weekDays);

        var natDays = [
          [1, 1, 'uk'],
          [12, 25, 'uk'],
          [12, 26, 'uk']
        ];

        function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
            var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
            if (noWeekend[0]) {
                return nationalDays(date);
            } else {
                return noWeekend;
            }
        }
        function nationalDays(date) {
            for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
                if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == natDays[i][2]) {
                    return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
                }
            }
            return [true, ''];
        }
        function AddWeekDays(weekDaysToAdd) {
            var daysToAdd = 0
            var mydate = new Date()
            //alert(mydate);
            var day = mydate.getDay()
            //alert(day);
           // alert(weekDaysToAdd);
            weekDaysToAdd = weekDaysToAdd - (5 - day)
            if ((5 - day) < weekDaysToAdd || weekDaysToAdd == 1) {
                daysToAdd = (5 - day) + 2 + daysToAdd
            } else { // (5-day) >= weekDaysToAdd
                daysToAdd = (5 - day) + daysToAdd
            }
            while (weekDaysToAdd != 0) {
                var week = weekDaysToAdd - 5
                if (week > 0) {
                    daysToAdd = 7 + daysToAdd
                    weekDaysToAdd = weekDaysToAdd - 5
                } else { // week < 0
                    daysToAdd = (5 + week) + daysToAdd
                    weekDaysToAdd = weekDaysToAdd - (5 + week)
                }
            }

            return daysToAdd;
        }

        $('#datepicker').datepicker(
        {
            inline: true,
            beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
            altField: '#txtCollectionDate',
            showOn: "both",
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",

            changeFirstDay: false,
            minDate: dateMin
        });
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

anybody knows how to diable this national days