# Creating a calendar for events scheduling

Tags: php

I want to create something like this:

[image]

I've been able to create it statically, just type int everything fixed in the code. I want to have it done dynamically, I've built the database which consists of all the data I need to have in this table.

But what I can't figure out how to achieve is the first two rows (Day and Date). Other than that, I can fill all from the data base (Group Members and data associated with.

Can someone direct me on how to achieve first two rows? or should I also set them with the data in the database?

***EDIT***

I need at least how to convert the day (1-Nov) to day. I will use current year (2013) or next year (2014) for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may usefull following links. you can start from here and then can analyse there codes.

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037553/disable-dates-in-jquery-calendar-between-todays-date-and-set-date-and-also-week) [link 2](http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php?cPage=3)

Comment: Thank you, but the two links will not provide what I need

Comment: All I need is to generate the first two rows of the table using pure PHP no CSS needed

Comment: yeah, but you can analyse there codes, How the calenders written. It's open to edit.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712761/how-to-find-day-of-week-in-php it helped me yet I have to store the date in the DB .. This is OK for me .. Thanks for your support.